# iOS AVAudioPlayer does not play while finger panning MKMapView

Tags: ios, audio, mkmapview, avaudioplayer

I have a basic beep sound that I loaded with AVAudioPlayer in my app.

It can play the beep fine if my finger isn't panning my MKMapView.

My beep is set to play every 2 seconds.

When I start panning the map view, and don't take my finger off the screen, the beep stops playing.

I recall NSUrlConnection also doesn't fire while scrolling a table view, I thought this might be the same problem but I couldn't figure out how I can add my audio player to the proper run loop.

I setup my player like this:

```
-(void)setupBeep
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/beep.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error opening sound file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

and I am playing my sound like this:

```
// plays a beeping sound
-(void)beep
{
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Anyone came across this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you scheduled your `-beep` method to be called?

I suspect you’ve added an `NSTimer` to the main run loop in the default input mode. The reason you’re not hearing anything is that while `MKMapView` is tracking your finger, the run loop is in not in `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`—it’s in `UITrackingRunLoopMode`.

Try scheduling in `NSRunLoopCommonModes`, which includes both default and tracking modes:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self selector:@selector(beep) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Also, be aware that `NSTimer` retains its target. A repeating timer will reschedule itself automatically, so you’ll need to call its `-invalidate` method to remove it from the loop and allow the target to be released.

**EDIT:** Check out Apple’s [Threading Programming Guide: Run Loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) for a much more detailed explanation.

Comment: I am using [self performSelector:@selector(checkUserInRange:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];   if user is within range, I call [self beep];  then I call [self performSelector:@selector(checkUserInRange:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0]; again at the end of my checkUserInRange: method. I might revert back to using NSTimer and add it to the commons run loop now that you have showed me how it is done.

Comment: Cool, reverted back to it and included your run loop code, seems to work fine, although there is a slight pause when it tries to play the beep sound but it's a minor nuisance that I think we can live with. Thanks :)